# Inconsistency in output of program using chr

Tags: php

I am getting different outputs for the chr() function in the web and the cli

using php -a

```
php > $x = 070;
php > echo chr($x);
8
```

and on the web `example.com/x.php?x=070`

```
<?php
var_dump($_GET);
$x=$_GET['x'];
var_dump(chr($x));
```

gives following

```
/var/www/html/x.php:2:
array (size=1)
  'x' => string '070' (length=3)
/var/www/html/x.php:4:string 'F' (length=1)
```

Why is their a discrepancy in the two?

Comment: integer vs string - the parameter has to be an integer between 0 and 255.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`70` as the exact integer value corresponds to **decimal** ASCII code for `F`, while `070` corresponds as the exact integer value to **octal** ASCII code for `8`.

In both cases the passed arguments are interpreted as integer, however prepending the number with `0` makes the interpreter process it as octal number.

```
bin\php>php -r echo(chr(70));
F
bin\php>php -r echo(chr(070));
8
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php reads

> To use octal notation, precede the number with a 0 (zero). To use hexadecimal notation precede the number with 0x. To use binary notation precede the number with 0b.

The URI parameter `070` gets converted from `string` to `integer` properly trimming the leading `0`, actually understanding the value as `70`, and the CLI interpreter takes it literally, as is.

Answer (score -1):

```
echo chr('070'); //string return F
echo chr(070); //integer return 8
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation to your code, such that others can learn from it?

Comment: `>php -r var_dump(chr('070')); //  string(1) "F"` and 
`>php -r var_dump(chr(070));  //   string(1) "8"`